# MVVM Structure: Factory, Model, Repository, or something else?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am using an MVVM framework (MVVMCross for Xamarin).  I have Services, Models, and ViewModels with pretty clear separation of purposes.

I now have a class that handles persistent Key:Value storage as JSON.  The class is used by services and interacts with models, but I don't think it falls into either one of those categories.  What would you call a class like this?  I would typically call this kind of class a "helper", however helpers are typically functional and static, which this class is not.

Any clarification on this matter is appreciated!

**Added:**
So to clarify, the class is independent of the data type, and part of instantiating is passing in the data type (or more specifically the struct or class), so it's would not be a repository on it's own, but a dependency or abstract interface for a repository. That repository would then be used by the Service or ViewModel.  Is that correct?

My current structure:

```
                        __ KeyValueStore
ViewModel __ Service __/ 
                       \__ Model
```

Propsed Structure:

```
ViewModel __ Service __ Repository __ Model
                           \
                            \__ KeyValueStore
```

Comment: Might be a better fit at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software architecture and design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion persistent data falls into the data tier. Where MVVM is likely presentation tier and you might have some core/business logic tier. To access that class which stores the data you can use the repository pattern (make the core/presentation not depend on the data layer).

But the naming of the repository interface could be IKeyValueRepository and the concrete implementation of that repository could be named JsonKeyValueStorage.

As you wrote "Repository" in the title i assume you know how to use the pattern - if not feel free to ask :)

Comment: To verify that I follow, you are proposing a data type specific repository (ex: UserDataRepository) with basic Get/Set operations, which would utilize the data type independent key value store?

Comment: That depends on your needs. I was proposing an independend data storage logic. You would register it likely in your dependency injection framework or use some service locator. The IKeyValueRepository would likely just have two methods (T Get<T>(string key) and T Set<T>(string key, T value) ).